# mp4から画像を抽出する

Tags: javascript, php, html

mp4ファイルからphpやjsで画像を抽出する方法はありますでしょうか？
また、htmlの工夫でサムネイル的なものを出すことは出来ませんでしょうか。

詳しい方、ご教示頂けますと、幸いです。

Comment: 参考情報: [Generate preview image from Video file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043007/generate-preview-image-from-video-file)

Comment: サムネイル抽出処理をサーバサイドで行いたいのか、クライアントサイドで行いたいのかは明記した方がよいです。

Answer (score 2):

使途等不明ですので性能などについては検証・言及しません。また環境も不明ですので最新の環境を想定します。

最近のほとんどの主要なブラウザはHTML5のvideo要素でmp4が再生可能ですので、
jsを利用できるということでしたらこのvideo要素で描画された画面をcanvas要素（videoでmp4がつかえる程度の環境ならまずサポートしているでしょう）に画像としてエクスポート可能ですし、必要ならさらにAPIがサポートする範囲で（あるいは必要なライブラリを使用して）任意の画像形式に変換することも可能と思います。
サンプルではシークバーで動画の位置を選択して、その瞬間の画面をcanvasに表示しています。

```
thumbnailView.getContext('2d').drawImage(videoRenderer, 0, 0, videoRenderer.videoWidth, videoRenderer.videoHeight);
```

がその処理です。（HTML5のvideoで読める）てきとうな動画ファイルをご用意の上お試しください。

> また、htmlの工夫でサムネイル的なものを出すことは出来ませんでしょうか。

こちらの意図がよくわからなかったのですが、とりあえずcanvasからエクスポートしたdata urlのjpeg画像を表示できるようにしてみました。

```js
var selectFile = document.querySelector('#sourceInputFile');
var videoRenderer = document.createElement('video');
var seek = document.querySelector('#seekInputRange');
var exportJpeg = document.querySelector('#exportJpegInputButton');

var videoRendererLoaded = false;
videoRenderer.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
  videoRendererLoaded = true;
  thumbnailView.width = videoRenderer.videoWidth;
  thumbnailView.height = videoRenderer.videoHeight;
});

videoRenderer.addEventListener('seeked', function () {
  thumbnailView.getContext('2d').drawImage(videoRenderer, 0, 0);
});

selectFile.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  var file = selectFile.files[0];
  if (file && videoRenderer.canPlayType(file.type)) {
    videoRendererLoaded = false;
    seek.value = 0;
    videoRenderer.src = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(selectFile.files[0]);
  }
});

seek.addEventListener('input', function () {
  if (videoRendererLoaded) {
    videoRenderer.currentTime = seek.value * videoRenderer.duration;
  }
});

exportJpeg.addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (videoRendererLoaded) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = thumbnailView.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  };
});
```

```html
source video file: <input id="sourceInputFile" type="file" />
<br />
seek position: <input id="seekInputRange" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.001" />
<br />
thumbnail:
<br />
<canvas id="thumbnailView"></canvas>
<br />
<input id="exportJpegInputButton" type="button" value="Export thumbnail as JPEG image" />
```

参考

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640869/create-thumbnail-from-video-file-via-file-input
- 動画がなければ[NHKクリエイティブ・ライブラリー](http://www1.nhk.or.jp/creative/)など